# How to fix trouble with css animation in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, svg

I have an svg-diagram that works properly in Chrome, but not in Firefox. I read some tasks about similar problems on this site, but the solution did not found. As i know latest Firefox browsers dont need vendor prefixes neither keyframe or transition. So i stuck a little.

Also i tried to add -moz prefixes  but it doesnt help

```
@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
        transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
}
```

Here is my code http://codepen.io/tvsjke/pen/OpVjON

I would be very grateful if you could point to the root of the problem.

Comment: "Works" the same in both browsers for me.

Comment: You may have coded against Chrome's buggy transform-origin implementation.